# Rename url on soap service

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I have a Eclipse project with a web and a SOAP service created with Axis.
It generates only one war.

My url for web and web service are:

http://server/webproject/index.jsp

http://server/webproject/services/service1?wsdl

How can I modify web service url context to be diferent like this?

http://server/ws/services/service1?wsdl

The url web must continue working on http://server/webproject/index.jsp

This is my server-config.wsdd

```
<ns1:deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/">
 <ns1:globalConfiguration>
  <ns1:parameter name="sendMultiRefs" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="disablePrettyXML" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="adminPassword" value="admin"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="attachments.Directory" value="xxx"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="dotNetSoapEncFix" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="enableNamespacePrefixOptimization" value="false"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="sendXMLDeclaration" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="sendXsiTypes" value="true"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="attachments.implementation" value="org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl"/>
  <ns1:requestFlow>
   <ns1:handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">
    <ns1:parameter name="scope" value="session"/>
   </ns1:handler>
   <ns1:handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">
    <ns1:parameter name="scope" value="request"/>
    <ns1:parameter name="extension" value=".jwr"/>
   </ns1:handler>
  </ns1:requestFlow>
 </ns1:globalConfiguration>
 <ns1:handler name="URLMapper" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper"/>
 <ns1:handler name="LocalResponder" type="java:org.apache.axis.transport.local.LocalResponder"/>
 <ns1:handler name="Authenticate" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.SimpleAuthenticationHandler"/>
 <ns1:service name="services" provider="java:RPC" use="literal">
  <ns1:parameter name="allowedMethods" value="*"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="typeMappingVersion" value="1.2"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="wsdlPortType" value="servicesSEI"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="className" value="services.ServicesSEIBindingSkeleton"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="wsdlServicePort" value="services"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="wsdlTargetNamespace" value="urn:services/wsdl"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="wsdlServiceElement" value="Services"/>
 </ns1:service>
 <ns1:service name="AdminService" provider="java:MSG">
  <ns1:parameter name="allowedMethods" value="AdminService"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="enableRemoteAdmin" value="false"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="className" value="org.apache.axis.utils.Admin"/>
  <ns1:namespace>http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/</ns1:namespace>
 </ns1:service>
 <ns1:service name="Version" provider="java:RPC">
  <ns1:parameter name="allowedMethods" value="getVersion"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="className" value="org.apache.axis.Version"/>
 </ns1:service>
 <ns1:transport name="http">
  <ns1:requestFlow>
   <ns1:handler type="URLMapper" targetService="services"/>
   <ns1:handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler"/>
  </ns1:requestFlow>
  <ns1:parameter name="url" value="/ws/services/services"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs:list" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSListHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs:wsdl" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs.list" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSListHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs.method" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSMethodHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs:method" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSMethodHandler"/>
  <ns1:parameter name="qs.wsdl" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler"/>
 </ns1:transport>
 <ns1:transport name="local">
  <ns1:responseFlow>
   <ns1:handler type="LocalResponder"/>
  </ns1:responseFlow>
 </ns1:transport>
 
</ns1:deployment>
```

Answer (score 1):

2 step to achieve this:

1. **Update the web.xml**

   find the **web.xml** file inside the **WEB-INF** directory in your eclipse project.Replace the existing **servlet-mapping** for the Axis servlet and update the **url-pattern**. For instance:

```html
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2. **Update Axis Configuration (**server-config.wsdd**):**

   Locate the .wsdd file typically located in the WEB-INF directory. Specifically, look for the **<transport>** element that specifies the URL for your service. Modify the url attribute to match your new context path:

```html
<transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender">
    <requestFlow>
        <handler type="URLMapper" targetService="service1"/>
    </requestFlow>
    <parameter name="url" value="/ws/services/service1"/>
</transport>
```

the url parameter is set to **/ws/services/service1**, reflecting the new context path.

3. **Rebuild and deploy**

Rebuild and deploy the project, the web service should now be accessible at the new context path, such as http://server/ws/services/service1?wsdl.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks so much, but it is not working.  It show me : The resource is not available

I have added my server-config.wsdd
Service name is services.